# How can I install my printer by terminal?

Tags: printing

I have an Epson TX 115 printer. The thing is that I could successfully install when I was running Ubuntu 13.10 but now that I have 14.04 I tried installing by the same way, using system settings, but after I press to start downloading and installing, after some time it does not respond any more. In the end I have to close it by force.

I also tried Cups but I can log in with my user and my pass... I don't know what's wrong.

Sorry, I'm pretty new about ubuntu, since I had windows a for very long time, so tell me if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

Download this file for 32 bits:

```
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-i386/epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-nx110-series_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
```

Or this file for 64 bits:

```
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-nx110-series_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```

Install the file using gdebi, requires some dependencies.

Use your distribution's printer setup tool or the CUPS web interface at:

```
http://localhost:631/admin
```

And go through the steps of the add printer wizard.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really works. After installing I add the printer by system settings - pritner since I said I can't use CUPS web interface. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: @Kevin Chang:If it works do not touch. Test Cups from Firefox started as root: sudo -i   firefox or gksudo firefox